# Using a Xib in another Storyboard

Tags: xib

okay?
I have immense difficulty and do not know where to start!
I created a library of functions map, but now I have to create a file within that library. Xib. Inside this file I have to insert a UIButton and UIText.
My difficulty is this, when the programmer is using my library it can import this UIButton and UIText to storyboard it. Then, he will take these two objects xib of LIB and use the storyboard of your software.

Does anyone have an example of this being done for me to study?